# I want to rename a file that has a random part (in its filename) to a specific one

Tags: python

I have some builds generating files, and they all have a random part in them (checksum number).

How do I rename them to a unique name and execute them in Python?

Comment: Could you give an example?  Sounds like the files already have unique names.

Comment: sure. one filename example would be "Tetris_4_2_R1244_W32_4dbg.exe" and the "_R1244_W32_4dbg" part would be changing according to the version/build. I want to rename this to for example "final.exe"

Comment: And they *all* shall ben renamed to `final.exe`?  Or is there a target name for each of the patterns?

Comment: this one (not bothered about all) to final.exe yes. thanks.

Comment: @pixie: How about `ren tetris*.exe final.exe` at the `cmd` prompt?  You could also write this in a batch file (`.bat`) to have an executable script.

Comment: from inside the python script right? that would be a brilliant idea and me stupid for not noticing earlier... only thing i need to run it from a .py script...

Comment: `os.system('ren tetris*.exe final.exe')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure there are never any underscores in the piece of the name you would like to keep, you can split it. `name = name.split('_')[0]`. This won't of course preserve the file extension, but if all the output files are exes, you can just `name += '.exe'`

**Edit:**

---

```
file_list = os.listdir('.')
for each in file_list:
    if each[-4:] != '.exe':
        file_list.pop(file_list.index(each))

for each in file_list:
    name = each.split('_')[0]
    name += '.exe'
    os.rename(each, name)
```

This is not very robust, and requires you execute it in the dir the exes are in.  If its something you're going to keep around long term or expect others to use, you should investigate regex and make it path agnostic.  I didn't test this- its just a hack, so use at your own risk; but it should be pretty benign.  It will try to rename ALL the .exe files in the directory.

Comment: would it be easy to provide some code? i'm a newbie - but trying ;)

Comment: thanks!i will try it. what if the build is in a different dir?

Comment: `os.path` will help you to merge path and filenames in an OS agnostic way. Else, just set the path in the script and be sure to add it to the filename in the file operations.  You can catenate strings in python with the `+` operator.

Comment: You give it a try.  If you have issues, post your issues and will help you with the errors or unexpected results.

Comment: i still find it difficult to do it from one directory below the one that the builds are... any help and I would be grateful. if not I would have to take the DOS approach. thanks again

Comment: If you don't have more than one file at a time to rename (as indicated by `ren tetris*.exe final.exe`) than thats going to be the simplest approach. I was under the impression you had multiple exe files you wanted renamed.

Comment: i do actually. i can just adjust my build machine to put them in different directories. in any case i would like to control it from python 100% so it would be good to know. thanks for everything guys.